# How to get the result as List<Class> in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I'm working with hibernate(4) and did the following configuration.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.myproj.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="empdao" class="com.myproj.dao.EmpDao">
    <qualifier value="q1"></qualifier>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
```

While implementing the basic query (selecting all the data from the DB) I'm getting the result as list of object but I want that result as List of custom class (in my case Employee). Below is the code snippet within the DAO file(empDao) for the same.

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();


try {
s.beginTransaction();

list= s.createQuery("from Employee").list();
s.getTransaction().commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
return list;
```

Here I'm getting the list as object array.. Help me to get the same as list of Employee class.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423664/hibernate-get-list-from-database/14427411

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend you to use TypedQuery instead of Query. For example:

**Instead of this:**

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
list = s.createQuery("from Employee").list();
```

**Use like this:**

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
TypedQuery<Employee> q = s.createQuery("from Employee", Employee.class);
list = q.list();
```

In first case, createQuery returns the object of Query class on which we calls list method. But in case of second one createQuery will return the object of TypedQuery.

Comment: Hey @DK Ansh, createQuery is expecting only one parameter that is QueryString.. And even I tried with createCriteria(Employee.class).. But not helpful :(

Comment: Hey @Veswanth, are you using JPA? TypedQuery was introduces in JPA 2.0. If you are not using so that there is no way to get generic type return from list() method using only hibernate 4

Comment: No we are not using any JPA.. Is there any other method rather than list() to get the generic type array?.

Comment: In Hibernate 4 version, generics was not considered by Hibernate team. So you will not found any of the hibernate methods/class accepting generics or returning generics types.

Comment: what if I use the latest hibernate version?

Comment: The best way i would command you to create Util class to map from List of Objects to List<Entity>. Or even you can using Apache commons to convert from List<Object> to List<Entity>

Comment: Hibernate 5 's `Session` has method to create a Type safe query:  `org.hibernate.query.Query<T> createQuery(String queryString, Class<T> resultType);`